# How can I rename the head key of an Object?

Tags: javascript

my Object has this structure:

```
{ 
   "head" : {
              "nestedObject" : {...}, 
              "someMoreObjects": {...}
            }
 }
```

how can I change the key "head" into i.e. "newHead" without loosing the child values?

Comment: Why did you mark your question as `(reactjs)` and tag it as React? This doesn't seem related to React.

Comment: I use state to save the object into... you're right thought thanks for your edit.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, { newHead: YOUR_OBJECT } )`

Comment: @Dan - that's a good succinct solution which you may want to post as an answer, but I think you want `Object.assign({}, {newHead: YOUR_OBJECT.head})`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using JSON.stringify, replace, JSON.parse

1. JSON.stringify will change object to string format
2. replace method looks for the head and replaces with newHead
3. JSON.parse will parse data to javascript object

```js
var Obj = { 
   "head" : {
              "nestedObject" : {}, 
              "someMoreObjects": {}
            }
 }


Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Obj).replace("head", 'newHead'));

console.log(Obj)
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqBKRb?editors=1010

Comment: Worth noting with this answer that any non-serializable datatypes will be dropped from the stringified/parsed object.  So if you have any functions stored in the object, they will not make it to the other side of this process.

Comment: yes @AlexanderNied, above mentioned code works for only serializable datatypes and won't work for functions and even dates, but OP requested for object which is not having functions and it helped for him

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do like that ?

```js
const oldObj = {
  "head": {
    "nestedObject": { // ...
    },
    "someMoreObjects": { // ...
    }
  }
}

const newObj = {
  "newHead": {
    ...oldObj.head
  }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: I took the liberty to make a working snippet from your answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe something like this would do the trick:

```js
const myobj = {
  "head": {
    "nestedObject": { // ...
    },
    "someMoreObjects": { // ...
    }
  }
};

myobj.newHead = myobj.head;

delete myobj.head;

console.log(myobj)
```

Basically just assign the value of `head` to the new property name (`newHead`), then delete the old property name.

Comment: Same thing as above, I made a snippet with your code, it works.

Comment: @JeremyThille -- Thanks! 